# ionic angular works differently for ng-bind and {{}} don't know why?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am trying to implement ionic UI with its blank template.
here is my home.ts file thats inside /pages/home/ folder.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  items = [
   {id: 1,text:"first"},
   {id: 2,text:"second"},
   {id: 3,text:"third"},
   {id: 4,text:"forth"}
];
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}
  itemSelected(item){   
    item.text+=" Checked";
    alert(item.text);
  }
}
```

and here is home.html file.

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list inset>    
  <button ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="itemSelected(item)">
    <p>{{ item.id }} <span ng-bind="item.text"></span></p>    
  </button>
</ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

here if i use **{{item.text}}** instead of  than value get display but i want to know why  ng-bind is not working as rendering frequency of ng-bind is higher than {{}}.

Comment: What are you getting in the `span` then?

Comment: @Mr_Perfect nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ng-bind` is AngularJS (Angular 1) directive. If you want to do binding in alternative way then use `[innerHTML]` attribute binding.

```
<p>{{ item.id }} <span [innerHTML]="item.text"></span></p>
```

Comment: thanks @PankajParkar anoop just came earlier 4 minutes than you. so i select his answer.

Comment: @NisargDesai I don't mind about it.. but I answered 1 minute earlier than him.. You could check answer timings, Thanks :)

Comment: @NisargDesai This answer was the first

Comment: @PankajParker Yeah may be when i was writing first comment at that time i seen notification when i clicked i did got two answer and first was one i get attention so i confuse both did show 5 minutes ago and when i did try to accept your answer its shows me that you can not accept answer with in 2 minutes and when i try to accept anoop than it done. anyway i appreciate your help.

Comment: @NisargDesai, PankajParkar : I don't mind it too., your problem needs to be solved.. and I didn't noticed his answer before posting.. :)

Comment: Thanks to both of you. both of you have great spirit of engineering.

Answer (score 1):

`ng-bind` is not part of angular2, use `[innerHTML]` instead,

Comment: okay got it. it works now. i did not no that in ionic 3.0 they did upgrade package dependency.  thanks

Comment: glad to help :), and yes angular2 is about more of using existing HTML attributes., not custom.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's angular 1 style. For Angular 2, I use < span [innerHtml]="item.text"> < /span>

Answer (score 0):

```html
<span [innerHTML]="item.text"></span></p>
```